# Is there an Android (webserver) app, allowing running a limited set of scripts on the device, remotely?

Tags: remote-control, scripts

I was wondering, if there is some sort of an app, or a way, to run limited number of scripts or commands on an Android device over the network.

My use case is this: the device I have is inaccessible, and sometimes I'd like to turn it off, and turn the screen on. Since I cannot really touch the device to turn screen off (and use existing apps that deal with that use case), I'd like to have an app that starts a listening server on some port (say 7799) - which I could then access in a web browser on the local network via URL like, say, `http:192.168.0.50:7799/run?script=screenoff.sh`, which when processed by the server, would then blackout the screen.

I'm aware that I could enable `adb` (default port 5555) over TCP/IP ([How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)), which basically enables this functionality - but I do not want the *entire* Android system open on the local network permanently. I'd just want to have only *some* functions (i.e. `.sh` scripts, something that could run in `adb`), that I myself choose, accessible/triggerable through a web server (that runs/keeps its port open permanently, and is thus started as a system service at boot of device).

Is there any application - or possibly, even a method in Android itself - that can be used for functionality like this?

Comment: Please note that recommendations like *Is there an app for X* are off-topic here (see [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic) for details). For where your question might fit better, you might want to look into [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) and [Where to ask for app recommendations?](//android.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575).

Comment: Thanks @Izzy - good to know; in my defense, I hope that the question is clear, that I'm *also* interested in solution that would be just a bash script (e.g. like start stop daemon bash script) that could run in an Android shell, in which case I wouldn't really consider it "app recommendation" (and all of the marketing mess that comes out of that, which is, I guess, the mean reason sites want to discourage that). So, I hope this question is allowed to stand on this site ... EDIT: ah, bash script is off topic too, says the FAQ.. oh well, if this needs to be deleted, then delete it.

Comment: The reason I left it open was exactly your closing paragraph. May I suggest to rephrase your question along the lines of "how can I achieve this"? That would then totally be on-topic here – even if the answer might be an app, a shell script or any other software. Answering with an app that solves an issue is fine here – just explicitly asking for an app is not.